How to control rive joystick using a number input?
I have a community file which has 2 joysticks. I want to programatically control the joystick's handle using input number between 0 to 100.
I read the documentation to do the same but couldn't find any relevant documentation.

The gist is to have two timelines with the min and max values(0 and 100) set in each their first frames respectively and then blend those two timelines together controlled by the input.
You can preview the following example here (see the progress input number):
https://rive.app/community/files/3674-7674-download-progress-bar/
